# How to run tests with tox.ini

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, python-3.7, tox

I am reading and trying to understand some libraries online, and I come across the following:

1. Tests with no pytest or unitest

I am reading online and I found a **tox.ini** file like the following:

```
[tox]
envlist =
    py27
    py35
    py36
    py37
    flake8

[testenv:flake8]
basepython = python
deps = flake8
commands = flake8 related

[testenv]
setenv =
    PYTHONPATH = {toxinidir}:{toxinidir}/related

deps =
    -r{toxinidir}/dev-requirements.txt

commands =
    pip install -U pip
    py.test --basetemp={envtmpdir}
```

I am still not being able to make it run. I did the following:

```
pip install -U pip
py.test --basetemp={envtmpdir}
py.tests --basetemp={py37}

usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: --mccabe --pep8 --flake8
  inifile: /home/tmhdev/Documents/related/pytest.ini
  rootdir: /home/tmhdev/Documents/related
```

How can I run the tests in this file?
The library is called related: https://github.com/genomoncology/related/tree/master/tests

Comment: Those unknown options are in your [`pytest.ini`](https://github.com/genomoncology/related/blob/be47c0081e60fc60afcde3a25f00ebcad5d18510/pytest.ini#L5). Remove them, those are options for `flake8`, not `pytest`.

Answer (score 8):

[`tox` itself is an environment manager](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that can run a series of commands for you (think like `make` but it knows about python things)

Usually the easiest way to run tests when there is a `tox.ini` is to just invoke `tox` itself (which you can install with `pip install tox`)

If you want to reproduce ~roughly what tox is doing under the hood (let's say for `tox -e py37` above) you'd need to create a virtualenv and then invoke the tests.

```
# environment setup
virtualenv -p python3.7 .tox/py37
. .tox/py37/bin/activate
.tox/py37/bin/pip install -r dev-requirements.txt
export PYTHONPATH=$PWD:$PWD/related

# testenv `commands`
pip install -U pip
py.test --basetemp=.tox/py37/tmp
```